# Check the class-type of a file with preprocessors

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, clang, c-preprocessor

I'm using (clang) macros.

One of them is a `#define` for a macro that involves `self.view.frame` except sometimes I try to use this macro in a `UIView` class not a `UIViewController` class, so for that I'd need to use `self.frame` not `self.view.frame`.

Right now I have a master file `macros.h` which I import into every method-file. Rather than using `#undef` and redefining that one macro every-time I'm in a `UIView` class .m-file, is there any way I can check the class type in `(clang)` itself and change that definition in my `macros.h` based on the class-conditional for which class has imported my `macros.h` file?

I know of the existence of `#ifdef` in clang but I've never used it and also am not aware of how to check class-types with it.

Comment: Does it have to be a macro? You can define one category method for UIView and another category method for UIViewController.

Comment: @MartinR Yes that is the solution I've gone with for now, I was just curious if there was a way to do this with macros; trying to learn more about them and their utility.